# i used the starup disk creator to burn 18.4.iso to a thumb drive i get an error

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, iso

i downloaded the iso from main website. used startup disk creator and tried to boot from it and i get this error

missing parameter in config file keyword: path gfxboot.c32: not a com32R image boot

I checked and in my bios its set for 64x

hope its a simple fix

Comment: When you downloaded the ISO, did you verify its hash sum against known good hash sums, per [the tutorial on how to verify the ISO](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu)?  If you did not, please follow this tutorial for the ISO you used, and see whether it validates as "valid" or not.  It sounds to me like the ISO might have been incomplete or broken in some way, and verifying the ISO would help to determine if that is indeed the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error output indicates that you are using an old version of the Startup Disk Creator where there is a known bug. (There is a new *cloning* version in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer versions of Ubuntu).

You can use other tools, that are not affected by that bug,

- **Disks** alias `gnome-disks` in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and newer versions.
- [**mkusb**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and newer versions as well as in many other linux distros.

See the following link and links from it, if you want more details about tools to create a USB boot drive.

- [Installation/iso2usb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb)