# Startup/Boot from USB error, fail to boot

Tags: boot, usb, 20.04, startup

I created a Startup disk on a 4GB USB drive using the Startup Disk Creator on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
Created a Startup disk of 20.04 LTS.
The process completed successfully and said that I could use the USB to boot up the machine.

Hit F12 on startup to enter boot menu.  Chose the USB drive.
It tries to boot, but always has an error.
Error reads:

Missing parameter in configuration file. Keyword: path
gfxboot.c32: not a COM32R image
boot:
gfxboot.c32: not a COM32R image

(repeats)

What is the problem?
How can I fix it and install 20.04 LTS on my laptop?
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [i used the starup disk creator to burn 18.4.iso to a thumb drive i get an error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068305/i-used-the-starup-disk-creator-to-burn-18-4-iso-to-a-thumb-drive-i-get-an-error)

Comment: This is due to an old bug in the Startup Disk Creator on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Please use another tool. Cloning tools are robust (and in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, the Startup Disk Creator  was converted into such a tool.) You can install and use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) and **clone** to use this reliable method. There are also other tools, that you can use, just tell me, if you don't want to install a tool via PPA.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that Ubuntu 20.04 only runs in 64 bit architectures and that you only want to install Ubuntu 20.04, you can simply run something similar to:

```
dd if=iso_image_file.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

Be careful and be aware that your device is "/dev/sdb", and change the ".iso" name for the name of the installation media you downloaded.

The USB musn't be mounted either, so umount the USB if your Ubuntu 14 mounts it.

Comment: This `dd` method is cloning, and is robust, when used correctly. But there is no 'final checkpoint'.`dd` does what you tell it to do without any questions, even if you tell it to wipe the family pictures in a drive, that you point to by mistake. For that reason some people use the nick-name 'data destroyer'.

Answer (score 0):

I use [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) to create live USB and installation USB sticks. It works on Windows, MacOSX and Linux and I have had no problems. I have failed with Rufus, dd, unetbootin and other methods that used to work well.